# Matrix with symbolic math gives a symbolic answer, not a numeric one

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, symbolic-math

Consider the following matrix

```
Ja(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6) =

[                                                                                                             (sin(t5)*(cos(t3)*cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)) - sin(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/5 - sin(t1)/100 - (219*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/1000 - (19*cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))/100 - (21*cos(t3)*cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))/1000 + (21*sin(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))/1000, (219*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/1000 + (sin(t5)*(cos(t3)*cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)) - sin(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/5 - (19*cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))/100 - (21*cos(t3)*cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))/1000 + (21*sin(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))/1000,                                                                                                             (sin(t5)*(cos(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)) + cos(t4)*sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/5 - (19*sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/100 - (21*cos(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/1000 - (21*cos(t4)*sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/1000,                                                                                 (sin(t5)*(cos(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)) + cos(t4)*sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/5 - (21*cos(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/1000 - (21*cos(t4)*sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/1000,                                        -(cos(t5)*(cos(t3)*cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)) - sin(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/5, 0]
[ cos(t1)/100 + (219*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/1000 + (29*cos(t1)*sin(t3))/1000 - (21*cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t3) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/1000 - (21*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t3) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/1000 + (sin(t5)*(cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t3) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))) + sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t3) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))))/5 + (19*cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/100, (219*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/1000 - (sin(t5)*(cos(t3)*cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)) - sin(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/5 + (19*cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/100 + (21*cos(t3)*cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/1000 - (21*sin(t3)*sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/1000, (29*cos(t3)*sin(t1))/1000 - (21*cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*sin(t1) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/1000 + (21*sin(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t3) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/1000 - (19*sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))/100 + (sin(t5)*(cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*sin(t1) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))) - sin(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t3) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))))/5, (21*sin(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t3) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/1000 - (21*cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*sin(t1) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/1000 + (sin(t5)*(cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*sin(t1) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))) - sin(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t3) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))))/5, (cos(t5)*(cos(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t3) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))) + sin(t4)*(cos(t3)*sin(t1) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))))/5, 0]
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                (21*cos(t3)*cos(t4))/1000 - (29*cos(t3))/1000 - (21*sin(t3)*sin(t4))/1000 - (sin(t5)*(cos(t3)*cos(t4) - sin(t3)*sin(t4)))/5,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 (21*cos(t3)*cos(t4))/1000 - (21*sin(t3)*sin(t4))/1000 - (sin(t5)*(cos(t3)*cos(t4) - sin(t3)*sin(t4)))/5,                                                                                                                -(cos(t5)*(cos(t3)*sin(t4) + cos(t4)*sin(t3)))/5, 0]
```

The problem is that when I put my arguments, MATLAB doesn't calculate the matrix numerically, rather it leaves it symbolically.

This is the result:

```
Ja(q(1),q(2),q(3),q(4),q(5),q(6)) = 

[                                                                                                                                                          sin(63/100)/100 + (219*sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100))/1000 + (19*cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))/100 + (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/125)*cos(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)) - sin(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))))/5 + (21*cos(157/125)*cos(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))/1000 - (21*sin(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))/1000, (219*cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))/1000 + (19*cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))/100 + (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/125)*cos(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)) - sin(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))))/5 + (21*cos(157/125)*cos(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))/1000 - (21*sin(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))/1000,                                                                                                                                                        - (19*sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))/100 - (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)) + cos(157/250)*sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100))))/5 - (21*cos(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))/1000 - (21*cos(157/250)*sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))/1000,                                                                                                                   - (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)) + cos(157/250)*sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100))))/5 - (21*cos(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))/1000 - (21*cos(157/250)*sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))/1000,                                                           -(cos(59/125)*(cos(157/125)*cos(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)) - sin(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100))))/5, 0]
[ cos(63/100)/100 + (219*sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))/1000 + (29*cos(63/100)*sin(157/125))/1000 + (19*cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))/100 - (21*cos(157/250)*(cos(63/100)*sin(157/125) - cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100))))/1000 - (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/250)*(cos(63/100)*sin(157/125) - cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100))) + sin(157/250)*(cos(63/100)*cos(157/125) + sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))))/5 - (21*sin(157/250)*(cos(63/100)*cos(157/125) + sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100))))/1000, (19*cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))/100 - (219*cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100))/1000 + (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/125)*cos(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)) - sin(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100))))/5 + (21*cos(157/125)*cos(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))/1000 - (21*sin(157/125)*sin(157/250)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100) + sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100)))/1000, (19*sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))/100 - (29*cos(157/125)*sin(63/100))/1000 + (21*cos(157/250)*(cos(157/125)*sin(63/100) + sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))))/1000 - (21*sin(157/250)*(sin(63/100)*sin(157/125) - cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))))/1000 + (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/250)*(cos(157/125)*sin(63/100) + sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))) - sin(157/250)*(sin(63/100)*sin(157/125) - cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))))/5, (21*cos(157/250)*(cos(157/125)*sin(63/100) + sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))))/1000 - (21*sin(157/250)*(sin(63/100)*sin(157/125) - cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))))/1000 + (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/250)*(cos(157/125)*sin(63/100) + sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))) - sin(157/250)*(sin(63/100)*sin(157/125) - cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))))/5, -(cos(59/125)*(cos(157/250)*(sin(63/100)*sin(157/125) - cos(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100))) + sin(157/250)*(cos(157/125)*sin(63/100) + sin(157/125)*(cos(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*sin(63/100) - sin(528276371951843/1125899906842624)*cos(63/100)))))/5, 0]
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 (21*cos(157/125)*cos(157/250))/1000 - (29*cos(157/125))/1000 - (21*sin(157/125)*sin(157/250))/1000 + (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/125)*cos(157/250) - sin(157/125)*sin(157/250)))/5,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     (21*cos(157/125)*cos(157/250))/1000 - (21*sin(157/125)*sin(157/250))/1000 + (sin(59/125)*(cos(157/125)*cos(157/250) - sin(157/125)*sin(157/250)))/5,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -(cos(59/125)*(cos(157/125)*sin(157/250) + cos(157/250)*sin(157/125)))/5, 0]
```

Is there a way I can get real numbers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**: evaluate your symbolic expression numerically using `eval` or convert it to a specific type using [one of these options](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/functionlist.html#btgyshe-1), f.e. [`double`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) or [`vpa`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html).

*Note that `eval` may be twice as slow as using `double`, but is sometimes slightly faster too*

**Explanation**

The problem is that MATLAB does not evaluate your symbolic expression numerically, it only simplifies your expression mathematically.

*Example:*

```
syms x
my_function(x) = cos(x)
% exact algebraic solution is known:
my_function(0) % returns 1
my_function(pi) % returns -1
my_function(pi/2) % returns 0
my_function(pi/6) % returns 3^(1/2)/2
% result can only be numerically approximated:
my_function(3.1415) % returns cos(6283/2000)
my_function(1) % returns cos(1)
```

So, MATLAB is able to simplify the `cos` expression when the result is exactly known. In general, the result of `cos` can only be numerically evaluated, therefore MATLAB displays `cos` in it answer.

If you want a numerical result you can use one of the following options:

- `eval`: evaluates your matrix numerically
- `double`: converts to double precision
- `single`: converts to single precision
- `int8` : converts to 8 bit integers (alternatives `int16`, `int32`, `int64`)
- `vpa`: converts to variable-precision arithmetic, i.e. it allows you to specify the desired accuracy (number of significant digits) of the result

See [Conversion Between Symbolic and Numeric](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/functionlist.html#btgyshe-1) for more information

---

**Is using `eval` a good option?**

As pointed out by Sardar Usama, using `eval` (to evaluate a string) is often bad practice:

- [Evading eval](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/).
- [Alternatives to the eval Function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)

*But, is this the same `eval`?*

No, I don't think so. `help sym/eval` returns (in contrast to `help eval`):

> ```
> eval  Evaluate a symbolic expression.
>     eval(S) evaluates the character representation of the
>     symbolic expression S in the caller's workspace.
> ```

Also using the MATLAB debugger points out that it is a different function. However, the full explanation mentions that it evaluates the *character* representation of the expression, which can also be seen in the source code:

> ```
> s = evalin('caller',vectorize(map2mat(char(x))));
> ```

So, it uses internally `evalin`, which is similar to `eval`, to evaluate a string. This may not be very efficient.

*So, we should avoid `sym/eval` too?*

Maybe not, also `double` uses `eval` internally to evaluate a string:

> ```
> Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);
> X = eval(Xstr);
> ```

The difference is that `sym/eval` uses `eval` (`evalin`) for the original character representation, i.e. the whole expression, whereas `double` uses it to parse the final result, i.e. the numerically evaluated value.

**Conclusion**: for your example `double` seems to be the appropriate method as it is twice as fast as using `eval`. However, for the following example `eval` is somewhat faster (~15%):

```
my_function(x) = cos(x);
for i=2:100
  my_function(x) = my_function(x) + cos(i*x);
end
```