# evaluating a function at different points

Tags: matlab, plot

```
X(1)=-10;
Y(1)=0;
Z(1)=37;
for k = 1:6
   X(k+1)=(40*1/k)*(Y(k)-X(k));
   temp_sum = sum(X(1:k).*Z(k:-1:1),2);
   Y(k+1) = (1/k)*(-12*X(k)-temp_sum+28*Y(k));
   temp_sum = sum(X(1:k).*Y(k:-1:1),2);
   Z(k+1) = (1/k)*(temp_sum-3*Z(k));
end
syms t;
x=sym('x(t)');
sumtempp=('sumtempp(t)');
y=sym('y(t)');
z=sym('z(t)');
x=0;
for k=1:7
   sumtempp =X(k)*(power(t,k-1));
   x=x+sumtempp;
end
```

I want to evaluate x at multiple equally spaced values of t. How do i do that, the function is not always a polynomial but in this it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `subs`

```
values=subs(x,3:0.4:10);
```

If you want the floating point valued result, just do `eval(values)` (note, this is sym/eval, use `eval` only for symbolic stuff)

Comment: how do i plot this againt the t axis? i need to do this at last

Comment: @Upstart `plot(t,values)`

Comment: Note that using `double` instead of `eval` may be faster (on average) as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380910/7621674).