# How to get value of symbolic expression for further processing

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, variable-declaration, floating-point-conversion

When using symbolic expression, the question is how to convert symbolic value to discrete value and obtain z value.

```
x=2
syms x
y=x^2

z=x+y
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix with symbolic Math does not make the calculus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369002/matrix-with-symbolic-math-does-not-make-the-calculus)

Comment: See [`subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) and [`sym/double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html). This is pretty basic stuff for symbolic math in Matlab. I recommend that you read through the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/performing-symbolic-computations.html) before proceeding.

Comment: @Horchler:I searched documentation and googled some search strings. However, I did not reach to what you are pointing at. Perhaps, I wont have posted. But, Jose answer is great and an alternative solution has emerged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
syms x y
y = x^2
z = x+y

y_function = matlabFunction(y);
z_function = matlabFunction(z);

x = 2;
z_function(2)
```