# How to find critical points x and y using a vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, vector

```
solve([3*x^2-2*y^2+y,x-2*y-4*x*y]==[0,0])

ans = 
    x: [4×1 sym]
    y: [4×1 sym]
```

I would like to find critical points x and y.  How do I get the output to result in numerical answers for x and y?

Comment: Use `double`: `s = solve([3*x^2-2*y^2+y,x-2*y-4*x*y]==[0,0]); double(s.x), double(s.y)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix with symbolic math gives a symbolic answer, not a numeric one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369002/matrix-with-symbolic-math-gives-a-symbolic-answer-not-a-numeric-one)